# MySQL Householding: Group Duplicate Addresses And Update Names to Include Both People

Tags: mysql, group-by

If we assume that I already have a query that presented me with the data I want in a very simple way for a mailer: Name, Address, City, State, Zip. But if the file's around 20k, there are a decent amount of people who have the exact same address.

Obviously it's simple to do a `GROUP BY Address` to remove any duplicates. But the problem I'm running into is not being able to update the names to include both people for a mailer.

If this is two rows in the original data:

```
Name              Address                City        State   Zip
Jerry Seinfeld    129 West 81st Street   New York    NY      10024
Elaine Benes      129 West 81st Street   New York    NY      10024
```

I would like the query output to result in one row where the name looks like this:

```
Name                           Address                City        State   Zip
Jerry Seinfeld & Elaine Benes  129 West 81st Street   New York    NY      10024
```

And if we want to get fancier, it would be great if they also had the same last name to include something for that in the script so that if both of their last names were "Seinfeld," the output would be:

```
Name                      Address                City        State   Zip
Jerry & Elaine Seinfeld   129 West 81st Street   New York    NY      10024
```

So generally, I'm just looking for some `SELECT *`-type query that households these addresses but also includes something to update the names. Thanks!

Comment: `RDBMS` is not the best tool for string manipulation, it's better done in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query would work well, Self tested:

```
SELECT 
    IF(COUNT(T1.Address) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.Last) FROM t1 T2 WHERE T2.Address = T1.Address), GROUP_CONCAT(T1.First," ",T1.Last SEPARATOR ' & '), CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(T1.First SEPARATOR ' & '), ' ',T1.Last)) Name
FROM t1 T1
GROUP BY T1.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT()

Examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks! `GROUP_CONCAT` is definitely close -- but is there any way to do the same last name trick I'm looking for also?

Comment: @Ryan group_concat will solve you purpose, which explained in question, you just need to pass delimiter in case, it's required other than comma

Comment: @kamalpal      Yup! It's definitely close -- used this and it's almost there: `SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(First," ",Last SEPARATOR ' & ')
FROM t1
GROUP BY Address` Just trying to figure out if there's a way to do the last name trick I described above also.